# TYPO3 news (tx_news) ordering of records not working

Tags: typo3

I'm running TYPO3 V6 and the latest version of tx_news (not tt_news) and when I attempt to change the order of sorting for the LIST display, the settings in the plugin are not overriding the Typoscript settings.  There doesn't seem to be a way to change to sort order of articles in the list view.  I am aware that flagging a news record as "top news" will float it to the top of the list, but none of my records have that flag set.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: No problem here. I'm using TYPO3 6.1.5 and tx_news 2.2.0 and do not have any problems with ordering. Both ascending and descending sorting of the desired fields work fine.

Comment: It does suggest it's a config issue at my end in that case.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Can you post the entire TS configuration for `plugin.tx_news` on that given page? As far as I know does this extension provide several options to override flexform settings.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem: My listview always showed the oldest news on the top. I've been searching for a solution for hours. As i wanted to start to change the extension files manually, I found the "setup.txt" in the configuration folder. From there I copied the following code into my Typoscript. The problem is solved now.

```
plugin.tx_news{
  settings{

    overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty = cropMaxCharacters,dateField,timeRestriction,orderBy,orderDirection,backPid,listPid,startingpoint,recursive    
    orderBy = datetime
    orderDirection = desc
    orderByRespectTopNews = 0
    orderByAllowed = sorting,author,uid,title,teaser,author,tstamp,crdate,datetime,categories.title  

    list{  
      paginate {
        itemsPerPage=4
        insertBelow=TRUE
        lessPages=TRUE
        #forcedNumberOfLinks=3
        pagesBefore=1
        pagesAfter=1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can ignore the pagination lines. Important is the orderby stuff.

Typo3 Version: 4.7 (not my fault :D )
News System Version: 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this one - basically I had been loading the TS setup code from an external file, which was overriding the default TS setup from the Typoscript template setup field, or rather, it wasn't.  I duplicated the TS code in the Typoscript template and the external file and finally it is being recognised and the fields can be sorted.